# Xpath to select all following-siblings along with the element matched

Tags: xpath

Suppose the HTML is like:

```
<h3>Ignore h3</h3>
<p>Ignore p</p>
<h2>Locator</h2>
<h3>Header 1</h3>
<p>Paragraph 1.1</p>
<h3>Header 2</h3>
<p>Paragraph 2.1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2.2.</p>
<p>Paragraph 2.3.</p>
<h4>test header 4</h4>
```

And what I want is to find the h2 which has the text `"Locator"` in it ALONG with the siblings that come after that. I've reached the following:

```
//h2[contains(text(),'Locator')]/following-sibling::*
```

It does get the siblings correctly but it doesn't return `<h2>Locator</h2>` itself. How do I get the selector to fetch both?

Comment: Please ALWAYS say which XPath version you are using. These problems tend to be much easier with XPath 2.0 or 3.1, but many people are still stuck with 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `self` also to achieve this:

```
//h2[contains(text(),'Locator')]/(following-sibling::*|self::*)
```

See link: http://xpather.com/ri9VYf0n

Comment: As alternative: `//h2[contains(text(),'Locator')]/(.|following-sibling::*)`

Comment: Good one, but I'm not sure that this syntax is acceptable in XPath 1.0

Comment: ,Its also fine in terms or returning `text()` only of `self()`  if required as `node()` then `self::*` is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to start from *first preceding sibling*:

```
//h2[contains(text(),'Locator')]/preceding-sibling::*[1]/following-sibling::*
```

but this won't work in case target `h2` node is the first child (has no preceding siblings)

So it's better to use:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h2[.="Locator"]] | //h2[.="Locator"]
```

to select all following siblings of "Locator" header and the header itself.

Or the same with your initial XPath

```
//h2[contains(text(),'Locator')]/following-sibling::* | //h2[contains(text(),'Locator')]
```